# Dart - Request GET with cookie

Tags: request, dart, setcookie

I'm trying to make a get request but I need to put the cookie.

Using the curl works:

`curl -v --cookie "sessionid=asdasdasqqwd" <my_site>`

But the function below does not bring anything

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as parser;
import 'package:html/dom.dart';

...
parseHtml() async {
   http.Response response = await http.get (
     <my_site>,
     headers: {"sessionid": "asdasdasqqwd"}
   );
   Document document = parser.parse (response.body);
   print(document.text);
}
```

Would there be any way to put the cookie on the get request in Dart?

Comment: Hey, can you look into it please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73133740/401-unauthorized-error-in-flutter-but-works-fine-in-postman

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `http.get(Url, Headers Map)` function and manually create your cookies in the header map, but it is easier to make a request with cookies included by using `HttpClient`:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:html/dom.dart';
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as parser;

parseHtml() async {
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  HttpClientRequest clientRequest =
      await client.getUrl(Uri.parse("http: //www.example.com/"));
  clientRequest.cookies.add(Cookie("sessionid", "asdasdasqqwd"));
  HttpClientResponse clientResponse = await clientRequest.close();
  clientResponse.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((body) {
    Document document = parser.parse(body);
    print(document.text);
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey, can you look into it please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73133740/401-unauthorized-error-in-flutter-but-works-fine-in-postman

Answer (score 6):

To complement the answer:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:html/dom.dart';
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as parser;

parseHtml() async {
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  HttpClientRequest clientRequest =
      await client.getUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/"));
  clientRequest.cookies.add(Cookie("sessionid", "asdasdasqqwd"));
  HttpClientResponse clientResponse = await clientRequest.close();
  clientResponse.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((body) {
    Document document = parser.parse(body);
    print(document.text); // null

    for(Element element in document.getElementsByClassName('your_class')) {
      ...
    }
  });
}
```

The code above worked perfectly well as well as the code below works perfectly:

```
parseHtml() async {
  http.Response response = await http.get(
    'http://www.example.com/',
    headers: {'Cookie': 'sessionid=asdasdasqqwd'}
  );
  Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
  print(document.text); // null

  for(Element element in document.getElementsByClassName('your_class')) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the following method, in addition to rafaelcb21's answer above:

```
String stringifyCookies(Map<String, String> cookies) =>
      cookies.entries.map((e) => '${e.key}=${e.value}').join('; ');

// Used like so..
http.response response = await http.get(
      'https://google.com', 
      headers: { 'Cookie': stringifyCookies(cookies) });
```

Comment: It's defined in the first line above

Comment: Good and dynamic solution.

Comment: Hey, can you look into it please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73133740/401-unauthorized-error-in-flutter-but-works-fine-in-postman