# Flutter - Send cookies without header using http package

Tags: flutter, dart, web, cookies, httprequest

I am using the flutter [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package. Is there a way to send cookies **without using header**? To be clear below is an example of doing so using curl:

```
curl --cookie "auth_session=abcd" http://127.0.0.1:9011/api/v1/login
```

Also, I'm using flutter for both **web** and mobile. Therefore, the io-library-based solutions are not applicable to web. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51934784/16245805) one which is not even using the [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package.

Currently, I'm using [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package like so:

```
final String uri = "www.example.com";

final response = await post(
  Uri.parse(uri),
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Cookie': 'sessionid=asdasdasqqwd'  // Don't want to use header
  },
  body: body),
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you found a solution to this ?

Comment: @KaranKhurana  Hi. No I have not. My question is for a long time ago and did not get any answer back then. Also I am not using Flutter anymore. Sorry!